# How do I make content only load on desktop?

Tags: performance, mobile, conditional-content

In order to improve the performance on mobile, I want to load some of the content on one of my sites only on desktop (this is content that is also not clicked on mobile). If I simply hide it via CSS, it is still loaded, so I guess it won't really speed up the site much.

Is there a way in WordPress to actually not load some of the content on mobile, so it is only loaded on desktop?

Comment: You can check it in your if statements using `wp_is_mobile()` function for example

Answer (score 0):

MemberPress is a WordPress membership site plugin and LMS that makes it easy to charge your users for access to content and digital products such as software, e-books, and online courses you create. ... MemberPress has all the features you'd expect from a full-featured WordPress membership site plugin.
https://memberpress.com/myohoguy/home

Comment: But the question isn't asking about membership plugins?